# Print on server using raw mode in php

Tags: php, printing

```
printer_set_option($ph, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");
printer_set_option($ph, PRINTER_PAPER_FORMAT, PRINTER_FORMAT_CUSTOM);
printer_set_option($ph, PRINTER_PAPER_LENGTH, 50);
printer_start_doc($ph,"abc");
printer_start_page($ph);
$font = printer_create_font("Arial", 72, 48, 400, false, false, false, 0);
printer_select_font($ph, $font);
printer_draw_text($ph, "test", 10, 10);
printer_start_page($ph);
printer_end_doc($ph);
```

I am trying to print in php on server (thermal printer attached to server) in raw mode.
 Is there a way I can change the font size? I tried using printer_draw_text but it doesnt work without start page. 
If I use start page the thermal printer will feed the paper for an about A4 size. Is there a way I can change font-size of the text?

Comment: You know, you can use a space character between sentences and a question mark at the end of a question :)

Comment: Oops. Thanks aleks will be carefull while posting further questions

Comment: Don't know anything about that, but `RAW` mode to me would imply that you have to manage control sequences (e.g. font size and positioning) yourself.

Comment: Mario thanks for pointing out to control sequences but I am not sure how to handle font size using control sequences.A reference would be helpfull

Comment: That's no magic thing. Every printer follows some control language. If not PCL, then some other: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_description_language -- So, depends on your printer. You need to research a lot (for your printer type, which you didn't mention). Heaps of effort. Which is why you won't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't printer_set_option() help ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.printer-set-option.php

Comment: Adrian tried printer set option but it again feeds to long blank page.I have mentioned the code I tried.

Comment: still that problem exist to me too... it feeds looong blank page